# Is it possible to request a stronger consistency level for a request than the default consistency level of the container / account?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I looked in the public documentation about this, but there appears to be some confusion around this, hence the question. I will start by describing the info I found, and then present the question. Please don't just reference the docs without understanding what exactly I am asking.

Looking at this [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq#can-the-read-request-consistency-level-be-changed):

> **Can the read request consistency level be changed?**
>   ... The key idea is that you can't set the request consistency level at
>   more than the setting for the table. For example, you can't set the
>   consistency level for the table at Eventual and the request
>   consistency level at Strong. ...

However this only talks about Consistency level for reads. Is it possible to have a stronger consistency level for writes at the request level?

Also if you look at the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-consistency#override-the-default-consistency-level) about overriding consistency levels, it doesn't mention any restriction about in which direction you can override the consistency. It appears to indicate as if you can move towards either stronger or weaker consistency at the request level.

This adds to the confusion. Also note that the FAQ section (first link above) I am referring to is specific to table API, so it could be also that table API has different capabilities regarding request level consistency than other APIs. However, it would be nice to have a clear explanation about this.

**Questions**

- Is it possible to have a stronger consistency at request level for
  reads? Do the possibilities change with the API?
- Is it possible to have a stronger consistency at request level for
  writes? Do the possibilities change with the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently was trying to figure out these same questions. But i believe the answer to all four is **no**. This is coming from a PM on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/7056677-allow-clients-to-specify-a-stronger-consistency-le)

> In order to support the data consistency guarantees of the DocumentDB service, consistency levels can only be weakened on the client side.
>
> On reads, can choose a weaker level of consistency and get the associated performance (latency) benefits. For example, if an account is configured with strong consistency, by default the read is served from a quorum of replicas. A specific client can choose to read from just a single client (better latency) at the expense of potentially getting a stale read.
>
> On writes, for example in order to support strong consistency DocumentDB has to ensure that every write is committed on a majority of replicas before it is acknowledged to the client. The write behavior cannot be changed because other clients might require the default strong consistency behavior.